# Showing only comments of a post in a new page

Tags: comments, wordpress

I've placed the following line inside the loop, to display a link to each post's comments.

```
<a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><?php comments_number('Be the first to comment!', '1 comment.', '% comments already!'); ?></a>
```

When I click the link it takes me to the single post page and displays the post content and the comments section at the bottom. I don't want to display the post since there's another link to let users read more of it but I just want that comments link to go to a page that displays only the comments of that specific post.

I tried comments_popup_link and comments_popup_script but the reason that they don't work for me is because I use facebook comments instead of default WP comments. And comments_popup only displays WP comments.

Comment: The alternative solution/question to this would be, if anyone knows, to implement facebook comments or a system like disqus or intense debate into the default _comments_popup_ of wordpress. I've tried all of them but unfortunately couldn't get them to display inside the popup window.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but maybe.

If you want to display the comments and the post content seperatly, do not use the API functions.

Add a GET-Parameter to the links like

```
<a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>?commentsonly=yes"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

Then edit the main loop inside your Theme.

```
if(!($_GET["commentsonly"]=='yes')) {
 // display post
}
// display comments
```